# How can we pass Variable value of child Pipeline to Parameter of another child pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have Main pipeline as Pipeline 1.In that Child pipelines are ChildPipeline1 and ChildPipeline2.

In Childpipeline1 I am passing if condition and inside of that I am setting a variable called as my_variable and I passed a value 'Yes' to that my_variable.

Now in ChildPipeline2 I am passing execute pipeline inside that I am passing my_parameter as Parameter value.

Now,I want to return my_parameter value as true for that I am using below expression
@activity('Childpipeline1').output.my_variable.

But it is not working is there any different expression to use.

I used below expression
@activity('Childpipeline1').output.my_variable.

But it is not working is there any different expression to use.

Answer (score 0):

There can be only 1 return value pertaining to a pipeline , so your expression within the parent pipeline would always be  :
@activity('Execute Pipeline1').output.pipelineReturnValue

Plz refer :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-pipeline-return-value